# loop through complex xml nodes actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, as3xls

I am reading an xml file in actionscript.

I need to loop through each node named "entry" as showing in below image :-

Can anyone help me ?

[image]

I am trying below code. but it not working :-

```
var categoryList:XMLList = x.feed.@entry;

                for each(var category:XML in categoryList)
                {
                    trace(category.@name);

                    for each(var item:XML in category.item)
                    {
                        trace("  "+item.@name +": "+ item);
                    }
                }
```

"entry" node also has some inner nodes, I also want to read those nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XML is using the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`, so you have to account for that:

```
var n:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var categoryList:XMLList = x.n::entry;
```

**Update:**
In order to access child nodes, you will need to continue to use the namespace

```
for each(var category:XML in categoryList)
{
    // this traces the name of the author
    trace(category.n::author.n::name.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcela :-), Now categoryList has values. But how can I get inner values of entry node. Again thanks for your efforts :-)

Comment: I've updated my example to include grabbing the author's name, however I was unable to find in the provided XML any element named `item`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to access in your above code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Better is:

```
var n:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
default xml namespace = n;
var categoryList:XMLList = x.entry;//no namespace type access
//etc
default xml namespace = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change declaration of `categoryList` to:

```
var categoryList:XMLList = x.entry;
```

It should loop through `entry` nodes now.

Comment: No, its not entering inside loop, categoryList is empty.

Comment: You can see the xml here :- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/animateyourlogo/uploads?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1